# Install sssd 2.7.0 and above not wrking

Tags: software-installation, sssd

I am trying to install SSSD by downloading the tar file. ( os ubuntu 22.04 LTS)
Download form this link:
https://github.com/SSSD/sssd/releases/tag/2.7.0
After running the "./configure" I go an error  error: tdb header files are not installed
Anyone has experience with upgrade/install of sssd??

Thanks,
Shay

Comment: What issue or circumstance has led you to believe that compiling your own sssd is a great idea?

Comment: I am trying to update sssd because the problem when you trying to work with group policy . ( sometimes I have problem with access of login)